# jQuery variable increment ++ not working in script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery function that switches between different status messages (p elements) with ID's ranging from status_0 to status_5:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var next_status;

    if (current_status < 5) {
        next_status = current_status++;
    } else {
        next_status = 0;
    }

    $(".status_visible").fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $("#status_"+next_status).fadeIn("fast");
    });

    //alert(next_status);

    change_status();
}, 10000);
```

My problem is that to start with, `current_status` definitely equals 0, but when it gets to my increment part, it comes out as 0 still! I tried this with a simple `next_status = current_status + 1`, which returned 01 instead of 1 (concatenated them), so I tried `next_status = current_status++` and it returned 0 still.

Can anybody put me straight here please :)

Comment: In addition to the pre-incrementing operator suggested by Huang Tao, you could replace the entire if/else with `next_status = ++current_status % 5`

Comment: @amnotiam: thanks for that, that's really helpful, and interesting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
next_status = ++ current_status;
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression `current_status++` means, "increment current_status, and evaluate to the old value of current_status," that is, use current_status, and then increment it after you note its value.

You want, `++current_status`, which means, "increment current_status, and evaluate to the new value."

Answer (score -1):

is your timeout method "setTimeout" going to be called multiple times? If so , you need to pass your counter as a parameter with global scope, otherwise it will be reset each time.